# How to add a new property in a specific level on Json using C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Json as below

```
{
  "name": "123",
  "properties": {
    "pcName-A": {
      "model": "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add a property as below

```
{
  "name": "123",
  "properties": {
    "pcName-A": {
      "model": "xyz"
    },
    "pcName-B": {
      "model": "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Newtonsoft library and do as below

```
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse("jsonString");
jsonObj.SelectToken("properties").Children().First().AddAfterSelf(
                      new JProperty(pcName-B,
                        new JObject(
                          new JProperty("model", xyz))));
```

Normally if I want to add property in top level I used to do as below

```
var propertyObjectToAdd = new JObject():
jsonObj.Add("property1", propertyObjectToAdd);
```

OR

```
jsonObj["property1"] = propertyObjectToAdd
```

Is this kind of easy way is not there for the above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to get the `properties` value as a `JObject` via a cast - then you can call `Add` on it to add the new property:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string initialJson = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(initialJson);
        var properties = (JObject) jsonObj["properties"];
        properties.Add(new JProperty("pcName-B", new JObject { ["model"] = "xyz" }));
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObj);
    }
}
```

Instead of `Add` you could use:

```cs
properties["pcName-B"] = new JObject { ["model"] = "xyz" };
```

... but I don't know whether there's any guarantee that the new property would come *after* the existing one.

Comment: Ordering is no problem. But here one thing missing is like how you concatenate the 'properties' with original 'jsonObj' after been assigned with new value?

Comment: @KBNanda: I dno't know what you mean - it's already *in* `jsonObj`. (Did you run the code? It produces your expected output.)

Comment: Yes my mistake. It works fine. Thanks. I assumed that just by adding into Properties the whole json won't get updated.